# javascript open parent window

Tags: javascript

The following is in the NewForm.aspx which gets executed from a parent page (surveys/lists/testsurvey/allitems.aspx). The javascript works and open google. However, it opens the google in the pop up window (newform.aspx) but i need to close the popup window and show google.com on the parent window (or whatever the parent window link is)

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function redirect()
{
  var inputcCtrls = document.getElementsByTagName("input");
  for(m=0; m<inputcCtrls.length; m++)
   {
       if(inputcCtrls[m].type == 'button' && inputcCtrls[m].value == 'Finish')
        {
               var funcOnClick = inputcCtrls[m].onclick;
               inputcCtrls[m].onclick = function () { window.location = "http://www.google.com/" };        }
   }
}

redirect();
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Use the `opener` property to find the window that opened the current window:

```
window.opener.location = "http://www.google.com/";
window.close();
```

Comment: getting this error. window.opener is null or not an object NewForm.aspx

Comment: @Mala Singha: Then it's not a popup window. How do you open it?

Comment: From sharepoint survey list. click on "Respond to this survey" opens NewForm.aspx pop up.

Comment: @Mala Singha: Are you sure that it's a popup window, and not an iframe in the page? If it is, you would just use `window.parent.location = "http://www.google.com/";`.

Comment: That works but messed up the original function of the button which is Add a survey to the survey list.

Comment: @Mala Singha: Yes, of course. You are replacing the original event handler, so that will never be called. Adding `funcOnClick();` in your handler might fix that, but as you are replacing the page it might not have time to work properly.

Comment: I tried this. Survey is added without bringing up the newform so i can select my answers. Also, redirect never works. inputcCtrls[m].onclick = funcOnClick() + function() {window.parent.location = "surveys/Pages/ThankYou.aspx";  window.close();};

Comment: Put `funcOnClick();` in the event hander: `inputcCtrls[m].onclick = function() { funcOnClick(); window.parent.location = "surveys/Pages/ThankYou.aspx"; };` (Note: There is no need to try to close the popup when it's not a window.)

Comment: inputcCtrls[m].onclick = function() { funcOnClick(); window.parent.location = "surveys/Pages/ThankYou.aspx"; }; This did not add the survey in the survey list. However, 2nd function worked (which opens the thankyou.aspx page).

Comment: If the function does a request to add the survey, then loading a new page will stop that request before it has a chance to be sent. In that case you would need to put your code in the callback for that request, so that you load the page after the survey has been added.

Comment: Actually, I am inserting the javascript in the NewForm.aspx. How exactly I can accomplish the "callback" with newform and javascript? Thanks